# Here maps javascript transparent object with higher zIndex hides other objects underneath it

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I am using [Here maps for javascript v3.1.24.0](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.24.0/api_reference/index.html).

My use case is to have a wide transparent polyline over another thin visible polyline so that I can make it easier for users to perform events like hover and tap.

However the transparent polyline with higher zIndex completely hides the polyline underneath it.

Is there a solution or a workaround for this?

```
const path = [
  { lat: 51, lng: 10 },
  { lat: 51, lng: 20 }
];
const path2 = [
  { lat: 50, lng: 15 },
  { lat: 53, lng: 18 }
];
const linestring = new window.H.geo.LineString();
path.forEach(function (point) {
  linestring.pushPoint(point);
});

const linestring2 = new window.H.geo.LineString();
path2.forEach(function (point) {
  linestring2.pushPoint(point);
});
const redPolyline = new window.H.map.Polyline(linestring2, {
  style: { strokeColor: "red", lineWidth: 5 },
  zIndex: 0
});
const transparentPolyline = new window.H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
  style: { strokeColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)", lineWidth: 10 },
  zIndex: 1
});
```

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sharmakushagra/nabsxez9/19/

Comment: Hello Kushagra, Z-index define depth of the map objects added to a map. You can alternate z-index of  both of the polylines so that the transparent one will come under the red one.   Regards, Here Support

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Thanks for your reply. I actually do need the transparent polyline to be above the red one. I expected that since the polyline is transparent, the object beneath it will show (that is also how it behaves in google maps). Is that not feasible?